# Subset of the 3-adic metric, is it open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In ($\mathbb Z$, *d*) where *d* denotes the 3-adic metric say whether the subset A={3k | k $\in$ $\mathbb Z$} is open, closed, neither or both.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am confused as to what the actual subset would like, from there I could probably work out whether or not it was open or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: The set $A$ is both closed and open.

Hint: To show both claims it suffices to use that for any point $n\in\Bbb Z$ the set $n+A$ is an open ball with the center at the point $n$.